# Apply CSS with ThyMeLeaf in Spring Boot Security App

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm asking for help today about a problem that I encountered. I searched for several hours on different forums. They all say the same thing but it doesn't work for me. I think I'm doing wrong, and it's for sure, but I don't know where.

I'm a student and I'm doing some projects to learn Java with Spring Boot Framework. My actual project is to create a program where you can transfer money. I need to Log In users via the database. This part is not a problem. My problem is loading the CSS file. I read multiple times that I have to save my CSS files in the: `src/main/resources/static`

With that, I have to add the `th:href="@{css/style.css"` in my HTML file to load css. I created a css folder in a static folder that's why I have `css/style.css`.

Here the link : `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../static/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" type="text/css" />`

The weird thing is when I launch my App, I can log in and I'm supposed to arrive at the root link. Instead, it shows me the CSS content. My link is localhost:8080/style.css?continue...

Can you help me, please? Here is my project : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUHCw.png)

Here is my page before login, without CSS : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yENoY.png)

And Here is my page after login: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFFHg.png)

I have two styles it's normal I wanted to test in different folders.

Thank you, I hope you will help me.

Comment: Please show us your Thymeleaf template for the login page. For some reason you are redirected to http://localhost:8080/css/styles.css?continue after logging in which is why you are seeing the css instead of the desired page.

Comment: It's okay all is working fine :D